# ES Modules: import named exports as module?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

funcs.js

```
export function hello() {
  echo 'foo'
}

export function foo() {
  echo 'bar'
}
```

index.js

```
import * as Funcs from './funcs.js' // import module, does tree-shaking work?
import { hello } from './funcs.js' // optimise imports, potentially clashes with other imports
import { hello } as Funcs from './funcs.js' // what should make sense, but isn't supported syntax

// this should be straight forward... 
Funcs.hello()

// vs having some random function on top level scope
hello()

// and this shouldn't work if I didn't import it
Funcs.foo()
```

That's my question. Does it make any difference to tree-shaking if I'm using form 1 vs form 2. Form 2 is preferable for expressiveness, but form 1 is the only way I can get everything into a module/namespace. Form 3 would be my suggestion, but maybe I don't know something that someone hasn't already argued against why this shouldn't be supported.

I have no idea where to go suggest this, or even to build a babel plugin to do this.

Edit: for context, I'm working with some newer libraries (rxjs) that don't expose default exports, and rely on developers to load all the functions they need. So I don't have control over those exports.

Edit: a workaround that was suggested was to simply create a global import file that imports all the globally required imports, and exports it all as a module, so that's what I'm doing for now.

Edit: found es-discuss. Will go there instead to forward discussion hopefully.

https://esdiscuss.org/topic/syntax-to-pick-named-exports-from-a-module

https://esdiscuss.org/topic/proposal-importing-selected-chucks-of-a-module-into-an-object

Edit: most enlightening discussion found here.

https://esdiscuss.org/topic/import-foo-bar-as-obj-from-module

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out I'm not the only one who has had this thought. This thread goes into more detail about some of the potential issues associated with this syntax... I don't necessarily agree but that's how it is.

https://esdiscuss.org/topic/import-foo-bar-as-obj-from-module

Answer (score 1):

For form 3, couldn't you just do `import { hello as Funcs } from './funcs.js'`?

Comment: No that means I cannot call `Funcs.hello()`, only `Funcs()`

Comment: I guess i'm confused on why you would want to call `Funcs.hello()` when there are 2 other options that would benefit from tree shaking.  It seems redundant. Even if it was going to collide with the name of a function from another import, you could just do `import { hello as funcsHello } from './funcs.js'` etc.

Comment: You can even do multiple this way:
`import { 
hello as funcsHello,
foo as funcsFoo
} from './funcs.js'`

Comment: I know... but please... read the question. I know I can do that. But that's too verbose and should be syntactically unnecessary. I know FP programmers love their functions but having to manually rename all functions like so into a namespace to prevent conflicts should be unnecessary. Why can't there be best of both worlds? If I have to load in two libraries in that have conflicting function names I'd have to rename one of them, and now their naming conventions are inconsistent.

Comment: Well I have found someone who has raised at least the same suggestion https://esdiscuss.org/topic/syntax-to-pick-named-exports-from-a-module so I will be seeing if I can push that forward.

Answer (score 0):

Form 2 will benefit from tree shaking.
`import *` means you dont want tree shaking and want to import everything. So webpack will do so.

Comment: Do you have a source for that behavior?

Comment: That's docs on tree-shaking... it isn't clear that unused members of a namespace import are not tree-shaked simply because they were imported that way.

Comment: I've read conflicting information on this. But yes I definitely do want to stick to Form 2, just that Form 3 isn't available, and I don't really like having stray function names lying around on the top level scope.

Comment: I believe `import * as Func` will make variable `Func` that contains property `.hello` and `.foo`. webpack wont remove unused object property.  But i cant find any code or docs about what i just said, its just what i experienced.

Comment: In my experince i can do `var a = 'hello'; Func[a]();`. Not exactly that but looks like that. So i can say it doesnt do tree shaking that way